# Getting Wide Space Above The Header

Tags: html, css, header, menubar

I am trying to make my header(.navbar) fixed but when i set the position to fixed i am getting wide space above the header i fixed it by putting margin (-22 0 0 0) but i m little confused to set margin in negative

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.navbar{
    height:86px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#0083C1;
    position:fixed;
    margin:-22px 0 0 0;
}

#site-logo{
    height:70px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#0083C1;
    margin:2px 2px 0 1px;
    float:left;
}

.navmenu{
    height:55px;
    width:800px;
    background-color:#0083C1;
    margin:15px 0 0 500px; 
}

.navmenu ul{
    float:left;


}

.navmenu ul li{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;

}

.navmenu ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:15px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family: arial,sans-serif;

}

.navmenu ul li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ffffff;
}

.navmenu ul li a:focus{
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ffffff;
}
</style>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <header class="navbar">
            <div id="site-logo">

            </div>
            <nav>
            <div class="navmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>                   
                </ul>
            </div>
                </nav>
        </header>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give following css. It will remove default padding and margin of h1 tag which browser taking.

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0; 
}
```

Elements have there default margin and padding.

You can remove it will all selector also.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yc5ozk6m/)**

Comment: i didn't use h1 in header.

Comment: @SameerMoin Check in your html. There is `<h1>Hello</h1>`